# How to update to .NETStandard 2.0 NuGet Package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I've a good old *.NET Framework 4.7*  *Class Library* in *Visual Studio 2015* currently using [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` NuGet package version 1.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/1.1.2). I'm trying to update this to [version 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/2.0.0), but I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

I see that the new version only supports *.NETStandard 2.0*. Do I have to convert all my project to either *.NET Core* or *.NET Standard* in *Visual Studio 2017*?

Comment: Have you updated the NuGet bits in VS2015 as suggested https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html?

Answer (score 6):

.NET Framework versions 4.6.1 and higher do support .NET Standard 2.0+, but only when using new tooling. Make sure you update to VS 2017 version 15.3.0 or higher and have the .NET Core SDK 2.0.0 installed and no `global.json` in your solution's directory hierarchy pinning a lower SDK version.

You may also need to install the .NET Core workload in VS 2017

Comment: Thank you, upgrading to VS 2017 solved my problem. Why does it make a difference to use VS 2017 compared to 2015?

Comment: For some reason I cannot build using msbuild (version 15.3.3) with the same exception, only from VS 2017 (15.3.3). Do you know why?

Comment: Do you have the .NET Core ("cross-platform") workload installed? it is currently required because it contains the necessary msbuild logic needed for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, it works after installing the *.NET Core build tools* workload in msbuild.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to convert your project to .Net standard 2.0 to use the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0 package.

Check out the below link for .Net standard 2.0 supported .Net framework version 
as of now the, .Net standard 2.0 supports only up to .Net framework  4.6.1

[.Net standard 2.0 supported api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Comment: Is this how thing are going from now on or is it only this package?

Comment: Most probably. :( cause .net standard will be the underlying common library for all other version to build on check this link out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: Since .NET 4.6.1 supports .NET Standard 2.0, this means 4.7 can also use the package. The error message indicates that an old version of VS/NuGet/SDK was used in the attempt to upgrade the package (see my answer)